# Diferença entre AWT e Swing na renderização de componentes

Tags: java, swing, awt

Quais são as principais diferenças entre as bibliotecas de construção de interface Swing e AWT, no que diz a respeito da forma de renderização dos componentes de ambas e a performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem dois tipos de componentes envolvidos, os componentes *heavyweight* e os *lightweight*. Os componentes *heavyweight* dependem fortemente de detalhes implementados em código nativo para funcionar (ou seja, C e C++) e por causa disso, o desempenho deles tende a ser (mas não necessariamente é) um pouquinho melhor, mas deixando-os bem mais difíceis de se utilizar, além de por vezes dependerem de detalhes específicos do sistema operacional sacrificando-se compatibilidade. Já os componentes *lightweight* são feitos 100% em Java, sem requerer código nativo.

Os componentes *heavyweight* são do AWT (por exemplo, `java.awt.Button`), enquanto que os *lightweight* são os do Swing (por exemplo, `javax.swing.JButton`). **O uso direto de componentes *heavyweight* é desencorajado há muito tempo.**

Todos os componentes do AWT são subclasses de `java.awt.Component`. Uma dessas subclasses, `java.awt.Container` é especial porque ela corresponde a um componente que pode conter subcomponentes. Uma subclasse especial de `Container` é a classe `javax.swing.JComponent` que é a superclasse de todos os componentes Swing. Essa hierarquia também significa que quaisquer componentes Swing podem conter subcomponentes.

O desenho de todos eles se baseia no método [`paint(Graphics)` da classe `Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-). Entretanto, não é recomendável se sobreescrever ou invocar este método diretamente.

Um redesenho de um componente pode ser forçado com o uso do método [`repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint-).

Um componente *heavyweight* que tem o seu desenho de tela sujo, pode ser redesenhado pelo AWT por meio do método [`update()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#update-). A implementação padrão, apenas limpa a área de desenho de todo o componente e chama o `paint()` para redesenhá-lo, mas implementações mais especializadas podem fazer atualizações incrementais ou determinar quais são as áreas que estão sujas e redesenhar apenas essas. Novamente, o método `update()` não deve ser chamado diretamente.

Entretanto, o conceito de desenho incremental e o uso do `update()` se mostrou confuso e quase sempre desnecessário, portanto isso não é utilizado para os componentes *lightweight*. Nos componentes *lightweight*, uma chamada a `update()` é na prática o mesmo que uma chamada a `paint()`. Nos componentes *lightweight*, o método `paint()` implementado na classe `JComponent` apenas chama os métodos `paintComponent(Graphics)`, `paintBorder(Graphics)` e `paintChildren(Graphics)` nesta ordem ([fonte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-)). Como os nomes sugerem, eles respectivamente desenham o componente, desenham a borda do componente e desenham os subcomponentes. Embora você possa sobreescrever qualquer um desses métodos, normalmente você vai querer sobreescrever apenas o `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

No final, em ambos os casos, quem realiza o desenho é [a classe `Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html). Entretanto, o AWT sempre vai usar uma instância da [subclasse `Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), então você pode fazer o cast seguramente se precisar para ter acesso a um conjunto maior e melhor de métodos disponíveis.

E lembrando que no final das contas, quem controla tudo é o AWT. O Swing é apenas uma camada por cima do AWT, e não um substituto completo. O Swing só é um substituto do AWT no que concerne a substituir componentes *heavyweight* por componentes *lightweight*.

Há mais um detalhe importante a se notar: [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) e [`JWindow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) não são subclasses de `JComponent`, então elas não têm o método `paintComponent(Graphics)`, mas têm o método `paint(Graphics)`. Neste caso, você pode então preferir sobreescrever `paint(Graphics)` invocando um `super.paint(g)` dentro dele. No entanto, no caso de `JFrame`s e `JDialog`s, talvez seja melhor acrescentar um `JPanel` dentro e então sobreescrever o `paintComponent(Graphics)` do `JPanel`.

**TL;DR:** Ou seja, no fim das contas, o que importa é que para implementar o desenho da sua subclasse de `JComponent`, você deverá sobreescrever o método `paintComponent(Graphics)`. Para subclasses de `JFrame`, `JDialog` e `JWindow`, você sobreescreve o `paint(Graphics)` mesmo.

Mais detalhes em http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: Com base na sua resposta, então pode-se afirmar que uma interface em swing é mais portável que uma feita em AWT? Já que ela independe do SO?

Comment: @diegofm Sim. Os componentes do AWT foram algo meio feito as pressas utilizando-se ganchos para os componentes em C e C++ que o Windows e o Solaris ofereciam na época do Java 1.0 porque o pessoal da Sun não tinha tempo para implementar isso e não daria para atrasar o lançamento do Java por causa disso. Entretanto, esses componentes não são flexíveis, são difíceis de se usar e dependem do sistema operacional específico. Isso foi uma das amarras que o Swing veio libertar como uma biblioteca externa no Java 1.1 e incorporado na JRE do 1.2, sendo muito mais portável que os componentes do AWT.

Answer (score 3):

Na implemenação, a diferença básica é que AWT usa as APIs de componentes visuais do sistema operacional onde a VM está rodando para criar componentes inteiros com praticamente todo o comportamento sendo controlado pelo SO.

Já o Swing, desenha do zero os componentes usando APIs gráficas básicas do SO, gerenciando a maior parte do funcionamento dos componentes por conta própria.