# Qual a vantagem de usar BufferedImage para imagens?

Tags: java, swing, imagem

Eu quero saber qual a diferença em usar `BufferedImage` e o método `graphics` para desenhar as imagens para o `ImageIcon`.

Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(bfImage, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(bfImage2, 10, 350, this);
    }
    public void desenharImagem() {

        try{

            bfImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Imagens/cenario.jpg"));
            bfImage2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Imagens/0.png"));

        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida, mas se a comparação é entre o método paint e carregar uma imagem via ImageIO a comparação não tem muito a ver, pois as finalidades são diferentes. O primeiro desenha na tela, o segundo apenas carrega o arquivo como um recurso para se usar no código.

Comment: Eu não compreendi

Comment: A comparação entre os métodos  desenharImagem e paint desse código não faz muito sentido, porque eles não fazem a mesma coisa.

Comment: Pesquisei na api do java, o que entendi que é uma subclasse de image, que possui alguns recursos.

Comment: bufferedImage é sim, mas não há relação alguma com o método paint. Esse método, como eu já disse, serve para desenhar algo na tela, não necessariamente uma imagem, qualquer coisa. O bufferedImage serve para carregar uma imagem como um recurso para ser usado no código de forma que o java entenda, ele não desenha nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A interface [`Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/Image.html) é a que modela o comportamento de objetos que representam imagens em Java.

A classe [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) é uma implementação de `Image` que corresponde a imagens representadas por uma sequência de pixels armazenada inteiramente na memória.

O [`Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) (bem como sua subclasse [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)) **não** representa uma imagem, e sim é um objeto que faz o desenho em imagens.

Uma certa analogia que daria para fazer (embora bem imperfeita) é que "*o `BufferedImage` é um papel, enquanto que o `Graphics` é uma caneta*".

Como você mesmo mostrou, o método para desenhar uma imagem em um `Graphics` é o seguinte:

```
BufferedImage bi = ...;
g.drawImage(bi, px, py, this);
```

Há também o método para obter um `Graphics` a partir de um `BufferedImage`, que é o método [`createGraphics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics--):

```
Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
```

Usando um `BufferedImage`, você até consegue acessar os pixels individualmente com os métodos [`getRGB(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) e [`setRGB(int, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-), porém isso costuma ser algo muito baixo nível para fazer coisas como desenhos de formas geométricas complexas, texturas, renderização de textos com diferentes cores e fontes na imagem, etc. Fazer isso daí manipulando-se os pixels diretamente é um trabalho árduo e difícil, e é aí que as classes `Graphics` e `Graphics2D` entram. Elas são abstrações que permitem a você realizar essas operações.

O AWT, sempre que ele chama o método `paint(Graphics)`, ele vai passar uma instância de `Graphics2D`. Então você pode fazer o cast seguramente.  A classe `Graphics2D` oferece um conjunto muito mais rico de métodos do que aquele oferecido diretamente por `Graphics`.

A interface [`Icon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html) tem a finalidade de ser uma figura utilizada para decorar componentes Swing. Por exemplo, [`MetalCheckBoxIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalCheckBoxIcon.html) é a implementação que representa o quadradinho das caixas de checagem. Já a classe [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) é a implementação de `Icon` que tem a finalidade de representar um ícone que corresponde a alguma imagem arbitrária. Utilizar o `ImageIcon` quando apenas o `BufferedImage` já seria necessário é conceitualmente errado, pois a finalidade da classe `ImageIcon` é mais para ser um adaptador entre as interfaces `Image` e `Icon`.

Ah, e não sobreescreva o método `paint(Graphics)`. Você deveria é sobreescrever o `paintComponent(Graphics)`. Veja mais sobre isso [nessa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176282/132).

Comment: Em resumo, são coisas diferentes que podem ser usadas juntas, mas nunca se substituem, correto?

Comment: @diegofm Sim, correto.

Comment: Eu não consigo usar o método paintComponent(), não esta funcionando.

Comment: @Juao É `paintComponent(Graphics)`. Entretanto, gostaria de saber, que classe é essa? E qual é a superclasse?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LuSGDDe7 Estava tentando implementar esse tutorial  http://www.pontov.com.br/site/index.php/java/48-java2d/123-a-primeira-animacao.

Comment: @Juao Desculpe, o nome é `paintComponents`, no plural, com o `s` no final. Falha minha. Já editei a minha resposta para corrigir isso.

Comment: É esse mesmo que estou usando.

Comment: @Juao Editei tudo e coloquei em http://pastebin.com/nkKvfF5d - O nome do método era `paintComponent` sem o `s` mesmo. Além disso, o coloquei dentro da `JPanel` e não no `JFrame`. Um outro problema é chamar o `repaint()` de dentro da sua `Thread` auxiliar, vez que isso é uma interação com o AWT/Swing feita de fora da *Event Dispatch Thread*. Resolvi isso com o `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. Só essas mudanças simples já fizeram bastante diferença - anes a sua bolinha piscava, agora não.