# Como movimentar animação em sentido horário?

Tags: java, swing

Bom galera, estou desenvolvendo um projetinho que visa simular o ambiente controlado de trilhos de trem, onde tenho 3 trens circulando em sentido horário, onde os três passam pelo mesmo local em determinados trechos. Minha dúvida primeiramente é, como fazer a movimentação desses trens que na figura abaixo representei por quadrinhos, e consequentemente poder alterar a velocidade de cada um dos mesmo.

[image: screenshot]

No meu código, tem apenas a parte gráfica, porque justamente não sei desenvolver a animação dos objetos.

```
public class SistemasOperacionais extends JFrame {

    public SistemasOperacionais(){
        setSize(1200,900);
        setTitle("Semáforo");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);        
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(300, 100, 300, 170);
        g.fillRect(350, 95, 10, 10);
        g.drawRect(600, 100, 300, 170);
        g.fillRect(650, 95, 10, 10);
        g.drawRect(450, 270, 300, 170);
        g.fillRect(445, 330, 10, 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new SistemasOperacionais();
    }

}
```

Comment: Pergunta *follow-up*: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226640/132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui assim:

```
package trens;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Trens {

    private static final double QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO = 20.0;

    public static void preparar() {
        JFrame t = new JFrame();
        t.setLayout(null);
        t.setSize(1200, 900);
        t.setTitle("Semáforo");
        t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Trilho t1 = new Trilho(300, 100, 300, 170);
        Trilho t2 = new Trilho(600, 100, 300, 170);
        Trilho t3 = new Trilho(450, 270, 300, 170);
        Trem a = new Trem(t1, Color.BLUE, 350, 100, -170.0);
        Trem b = new Trem(t2, Color.GREEN, 650, 100, 0.5);
        Trem c = new Trem(t3, Color.RED, 450, 335, 44.0);
        t.add(a);
        t.add(b);
        t.add(c);
        t.add(t1);
        t.add(t2);
        t.add(t3);
        Runnable moverTudo = () -> {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                a.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
                b.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
                c.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
            });
        };
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(moverTudo, 0, (int) (1000 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Trens::preparar);
    }

    public static class Trilho extends JComponent {
        public Trilho(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }
    }

    public static class Trem extends JComponent {
        private Color cor;
        private Trilho trilho;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private double velocidade; // pixels por segundo
        private double restante; // Frações de pixels que faltou andar.

        public Trem(Trilho trilho, Color cor, int x, int y, double velocidade) {
            this.trilho = trilho;
            this.cor = cor;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.velocidade = velocidade;
            this.setBounds(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(cor);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        public void mover(double deltaT) {
            if (velocidade == 0) return;
            boolean sentidoHorario = velocidade > 0;
            double distancia = Math.abs(restante + velocidade * deltaT);
            int tLeft = trilho.getX();
            int tTop = trilho.getY();
            int tRight = tLeft + trilho.getWidth();
            int tBottom = tTop + trilho.getHeight();

            for (int i = 0; i < (int) distancia; i++) {
                // Se deve ir à esquerda:
                if (x > tLeft && y == (sentidoHorario ? tBottom : tTop)) {
                    x--;
                // Se deve ir à direita:
                } else if (x < tRight && y == (sentidoHorario ? tTop : tBottom)) {
                    x++;
                // Se deve ir para cima:
                } else if (y > tTop && x == (sentidoHorario ? tLeft : tRight)) {
                    y--;
                // Se deve ir para baixo:
                } else if (y < tBottom && x == (sentidoHorario ? tRight : tLeft)) {
                    y++;
                // Se não for nenhum dos anteriores, o trem está descarrilhado. Coloca de novo no trilho.
                } else {
                    x = tLeft;
                    y = tTop;
                }
            }
            restante = distancia % 1;
            setLocation(x - 5, y - 5);
        }
    }
}
```

A velocidade da animação (não a dos trens) é definida por aquela constante `QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO`. Como está definida em 20, ele vai (re)calcular a posição dos objetos 20 vezes por segundo. Utilizo o `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` para chamar um `Runnable` a cada 1/20 segundos, arredondado em um número inteiro de milisegundos (ou seja, se você quiser 30 quadros por segundo, ele daria 33 milissegundos por quadro, e não 33<sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> milissegundos por quadro).

O trem azul está a uma velocidade de -170.0 pixels por segundo. Ou seja, ele vai bem rápido no sentido anti-horário.

O trem vermelho está a uma velocidade de 44.0 pixels por segundo no sentido horário.

O trem verde está a uma velocidade de 0.5 pixels por segundo. Ou seja, ele se move bem lentamente no sentido horário. Coloquei este valor pequeno para comprovar que ele funciona corretamente mesmo se a velocidade for menor que um pixel a cada passo e que ele não acaba nem ficando parado e nem forçando um movimento em cada quadro de animação.

Observe que tenho uma classe para o `Trem` e uma para o `Trilho`. Ambas herdam de `JComponent`, e portanto, são componentes Swing e desenhados pelo Swing. Onde é necessário, [**eu sobreescrevo o método `paintComponent`, e não o `paint`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176282/132).

Utilizo as chamadas a `EventQueue.invokeLater` para [**não manipular objetos Swing fora da EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132). Há três threads aqui: a EDT, a thread principal e a thread do `Executors`. Assim sendo, para que os componentes sejam manipulados apenas na EDT, as outras duas threads executam todo o seu trabalho apenas através do `EventQueue.invokeLater`.

Já o método `mover` da classe `Trem` descobre em que parte do trilho o trem está e move ele na direção adequada. A abordagem que usei não é a mais eficiente, mas deve funcionar no seu caso. Essa abordagem consiste em calcular a posição iterativamente, pixel a pixel de acordo com a velocidade, a fim de que as curvas dos trilhos sejam obedecidas. A abordagem ideal calcularia a posição final sem precisar usar um `for` para isso.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: O verde fica parado, é assim mesmo o funcionamento?

Comment: Perfeito @Articuno vc respondeu a pergunta e embasou de maneira clara e eficiente, mto obgdo. Agora vou tentar implementar o restante.

Comment: @CarlosDiego na verdade o autor dessa excelente resposta foi o Victor, eu somente comentei porque após lê-la, fiquei bem curioso pra ver funcionando. :D

Comment: @Articuno Não, o verde se move bem devagar. Observe ele com atenção.

Comment: Ah vdd, desculpa... kk Mto grato pela ajuda @Victor Stafusa

Comment: No caso para poder dinamizar e poder escolher as velocidade na propria tela, como seria?

Comment: @CarlosDiego Você poderia ter um método `setVelocidade(double)` na sua classe `Trem` e colocar em algum lugar um ou mais `JButton`, `JTextField`, `JOptionPane`, etc. para chamar os setters.

Comment: huum.. vou tentar aplicar @VictorStafusa

Comment: @VictorStafusa utilizei o componente Slider para setar as velocidades de cada trem, como faço pra jogar o valor do JSlider na velocidade do trem correspondente?

Comment: @CarlosDiego Deve ser algo semelhante a `a.setVelocidade(seuSlider.getValue());`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa atualizei meu codigo na pergunta, vc pode me orientar, pois nao to sabendo aplicar no codigo =[

Comment: @CarlosDiego Nesse caso seria melhor criar uma pergunta nova, até para chamar a atenção de outras pessoas também e evitar que essa daqui se torne uma [**pergunta camaleão**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pergunta+camale%C3%A3o).

Comment: Ah entendi, pois blz entao. Criar aqui, vlws