# Dúvidas sobre as classes Graphics e Graphics2D em Java

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Ando tendo muitas dúvidas em relação às bibliotecas gráficas de Java, que são as seguintes:

1. Qual a diferença entre sobrescrever o método `paint(Graphics)` ou o método `paintComponent(Graphics)`?
2. O que a classe `Graphics2D` traz de diferença em relação a classe `Graphics`?

Comment: Acho que são muitas duvidas para uma pergunta só. Recomendo que deixei apenas a 2 e a 3 que estão diretamente relacionadas.

Comment: Em resumo, [**swing é uma evoluçao do awt**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176271/28595) mas ele acaba por herdar muitas coisas do awt, como o método paint, que é o responsavel pelo desenho dos componentes no awt, mas no swing, a classe mae de todos os componentes foi reescrita(Component em awt e JComponent em swing), e foi deletado a paintcomponent o desenho da tela. Como toda classe na API herda de JComponent, e este método é o coracáo dela, acaba que ele é a melhor opcao para reescrita quando precisamos redesenhar um componente.

Comment: A segunda pergunta é parcialmente respondida no comentario anterior, somando-se ao fato que Graphics2D é uma evolucao de Graphics, preparada para fornecer melhores ferramentas para desenhos geometricos e formas, cores e outros detalhes na construcao de elementos. Ela fornece um conjunto de possibilidades maiores para desenho do que a Graphics.

Comment: @Articuno Então, ao utilizar elementos swing (como um JPanel por exemplo) é recomendado o uso do paintComponent?

Comment: Sim, porque tudo que tem J na frente é da API swing, e herda de JComponent, que é a classe que serve como uma especie de base pra todas classes de componentes em swing.  Se nao me engano, a propria classe `paint` passou a chamar a `paintComponent`, entao faz mais sentido sobrescrever a ultima para nao quebrar o desenho geral do que se esta fazendo.

Comment: Não sei se minha explicacao ficou boa, por isso nao respondi, mas se souber ingles, esse link é sua resposta completa para a questao 1: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html Esse outro responde sua pergunta 2: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html

Comment: Entendi sua explicação, muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. O método `paint(Graphics)` em componentes *lightweight* (esses do Swing) realiza essas três coisas, nessa ordem:

   - Pinta o conteúdo do componente propriamente dito ao chamar o método `paintComponent(Graphics)`.
   - Pinta os subcomponentes ao chamar o método `paintChildren(Graphics)`.
   - Pinta a borda do componente ao chamar o método `paintBorder(Graphics)`.

   O método `paint(Graphics)` também faz algumas coisas a mais para determinar qual que é a área que deverá ser pintada. Ele também lida com o caso de você estiver imprimindo o componente (para a impressora), chamando então os métodos `print*(Graphics)` ao invés de `paint*(Graphics)`. Veja isso tudo no [código-fonte correspondente](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29).

   Como você dificilmente vai querer alterar esse funcionamento padrão do `paint(Graphics)` (há pouca razão para isso), dificilmente faria sentido sobreescrever-se tal método. Assim sendo, sobreescreva o método `paintComponent(Graphics)` que é quem faz o desenho do componente de fato.
2. A classe `Graphics2D` é uma subclasse de `Graphics`. Ela tem diversos métodos a mais, basta dar uma olhada rápida no [javadoc dela](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) para perceber isso. O AWT sempre vai passar uma instância de `Graphics2D` para o seu método `paintComponent(Graphics)`, portanto é seguro fazer-se o *cast*. Se não me engano, a razão para isso é histórica, e o ideal seria que os métodos a mais tivessem sido acrescentados na classe `Graphics` ao invés de em uma subclasse.

Veja mais sobre isso no [tutorial da Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), embora a informação lá seja apresentada de forma desorganizada.

Também recomendo olhar o [meu TCC da especialização que terminei em 2007](https://www.academia.edu/24862059/Manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o_e_desenho_em_componentes_com_Java2D), onde abordei esse assunto.